# Winter fly problem in the UK

Tags: pest-control

I live in the northwest UK. On Christmas Eve 2018, flies started to appear in my living room during the evening. I have never had anything happen like this before. I have a very very clean house. The home is semi detached. It is now February 3, 2019. I have cleaned my house from top to bottom and sealed any spaces that might be vulnerable. There is not a space that I don't know about. However, the flies still get inside every evening. This is driving me insane. I am at the end of my tether  and cannot solve this problem.  I have scoured the internet for possible solutions but I have gotten nowhere. What else can I do? Can anyone give me any ideas I have not thought of already?

Comment: Do they look like "cluster flies"?

Comment: How do i deal with them?

Answer (score 1):

If they are cluster flies, you have probably sealed them up inside the home. They got in during the summer and laid eggs that are hatching now. Here is a [product to get rid of cluster flies](https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/cluster-fly.htm). You can probably locate something similar in the UK.